# Adding UI elements in Editor - Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

If anyone is aware of Omondo plugin for Eclipse, I would like to add UI elements to my own eclipse plugin editor, like Omondo does. e.g. adding a new class diagram creates a box with the class name in it.

How should I go about this development? I am a complete newbie with respect to Eclipse plugins and it would be great if I can get pointers for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For graphical editors in Eclipse, have a look at the [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/), [GMF](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/GMF_Tutorial), and [Graphiti](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/) projects.

Comment: Thanks Fabian.. Can you please tell me what Omondo uses for its graphical editor.?

Comment: @darkie: Sorry, I don't know - my guess would be GEF, which is the lower-level framework which is around longest (and which the others are based on).